# CFNotificationCenterAddObserver in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Is there any substitute for `CFNotificationCenterAddObserver` in `Swift`?
In [Apple doc's](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNotificationCenterRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFNotificationCenterAddObserver) I only find the reference to Objective-C, but I can't find any related code to use with Swift. Any idea?

The code I'm trying to write would be as follows in Objective-C:

```
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),
            NULL,
            displayStatusChanged,
            CFSTR("com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus"),
            NULL,
            CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
```

Edit: It's not a `NSNotification`([Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) that I am trying to use as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049020/nsnotificationcenter-addobserver-in-swift), but an `CFNotification`([Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNotificationCenterRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFNotificationCenterAddObserver)).

Comment: @martin-r The question you marked as a duplicated is about a different subject. Can you review it, please?

Comment: Your are right - I have already re-opened the question.

Comment: CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter() and CFNotificationCenterRemoveObserver() are available in Swift, but not CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(). (My guess would be that the "callback function" does not translate into Swift.) You should probably file a bug report at Apple.

Comment: @MartinR I don't think it's a bug. I have it from an Apple person that they just expect you to drop into C to pass callback functions.

Comment: @matt: OK, thanks for the information. - (But then it makes not much sense to expose a subset of the CFNotification functions to Swift.)

Comment: It really doesn't make much sense. Maybe I'll try to reach someone at Apple before open a bug report.

Comment: Update: Today, Apple announced Swift 2.0 and listed in the feature set was "Closures unified with function pointers". This may solve the issue of not being able to use `CFNotification`'s callbacks in Swift

Comment: That's true. But I can't check it now because I'm not working in this project anymore ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CFNotificationCenterAddObserver is available in Swift now. See [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNotificationCenterRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFNotificationCenterAddObserver).

```
func CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(_ center: CFNotificationCenter!,
                               _ observer: UnsafePointer<Void>,
                               _ callBack: CFNotificationCallback,
                               _ name: CFString!,
                               _ object: UnsafePointer<Void>,
                               _ suspensionBehavior: CFNotificationSuspensionBehavior)
```