# Swift: Keyboard Observer via NSNotificationCenter doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8

I'm trying to implement a simple keyboard observer in my iOS 8 Swift app but it really doesn't work. This is the code im currently using:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector(keyboardWillAppear()), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector(keyboardWillHide()), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func keyboardWillAppear() {
    logoHeightConstraint.constant = 128.0
}

func keyboardWillHide() {
    logoHeightConstraint.constant = 256.0
}
```

Strangely both functions to react to the keyboard are called once after starting the app. Nothing happens when I enter or leave a textfield. What am I doing wrong? And by the way: Is altering a constraint the best solution for changing the size of an image?

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe that `NSNotificationCenter()` is instantiating a new NSNotificationCenter each time you call it. Have you tried using `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `NSNotificationCenter()` is instantiating a new `NSNotificationCenter` each time you call it. Try using `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()` instead.

Answer (score 8):

```
//keyboard observers 
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillAppear"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)




func keyboardWillAppear() {
    println("Keyboard appeared")
}

func keyboardWillHide() {
    println("Keyboard hidden")
}
```

Comment: I am sorry to say this does not work, since it is a Objective C-selector. #selector(keyboardWillAppear)
#selector(keyboardWIllHide)
works for me
see this post: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049020/nsnotificationcenter-addobserver-in-swift

Comment: Of course it  works, and does work hence its the highest rated answer.  Please qualify your statement of  "it is a Objective C-selector" when it's written in swift

Comment: with the code given a get this warning in XCode: Use #selector instead of explicitly constructing  a 'Selector'
furthermore println is not valid anymore (I get an error) and should be replaced with print

Comment: Thats because at  the time it was answered (2 years ago)  it was correct for the version current version of Swift at the time.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, because you get informed if the size changes, if e.g. when suggestions are hidden/shown

```
//keyboard observers 
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange), name: UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

func keyboardWillChange(notification:NSNotification)
{
    print("Keyboard size changed")
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification)
{
    print("Keyboard hidden")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 and above code. Added code for getting height for keyboard

```
func addObservers() {
    //keyboard observers
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidAppear(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardDidAppear(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("Keyboard appeared")
    let keyboardSize:CGSize = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.size
    print("Keyboard size: \(keyboardSize)")

    let height = min(keyboardSize.height, keyboardSize.width)
    let width = max(keyboardSize.height, keyboardSize.width)
    print(height)
    print(width)
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("Keyboard hidden")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.0, closures:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil, queue: nil, using: { notification in
   // do stuff
})
```