# NSNotificationcenter does not have a member names 'defaultCenter" Error -Swift

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

Trying to add keyboard observers in swift and getting error

`NSNotificationcenter does not have a member names 'defaultCenter"`

using

```
NSNotificationCenter().defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillAppear"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter().defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

As advised from the following
[NSNotificationCenter addObserver in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049020/nsnotificationcenter-addobserver-in-swift)
[Swift: Keyboard Observer via NSNotificationCenter doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999605/swift-keyboard-observer-via-nsnotificationcenter-doesnt-work)

If I remove `defaultCenter` I don't get the error but, also no observing of the keyboard

```
NSNotificationCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillAppear"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`defaultCenter` is a *class method* (also called *type method* in Swift), therefore it is

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
```

and not

```
NSNotificationCenter().defaultCenter()
```

which would call the *instance method* `defaultCenter()` on the object
created and returned by `NSNotificationCenter()`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I copy and pasted that snippet from the most upvoted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999605/swift-keyboard-observer-via-nsnotificationcenter-doesnt-work and missed that.