# NSNotificationCenter addObserver in Swift while call a private method

Tags: ios, swift

I use the `addObserver` API to receive notification:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "methodOFReceivedNotication:", name:"NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
```

and my method is :

```
func methodOFReceivedNotication(notification: NSNotification){
//Action take on Notification
}
```

yes,it works!
but while I change  method `methodOFReceivedNotication` to private:

```
private func methodOFReceivedNotication(notification: NSNotification){
//Action take on Notification
}
```

xCode send me an error: `unrecognized selector sent to instance`

how to call a private method while the target is `self`? I doesn't want to expose `methodOFReceivedNotication` method to any other.

Answer (score 14):

Just mark it with the `dynamic` modifier or use the `@objc` attribute in your method declaration

```
dynamic private func methodOFReceivedNotication(notification: NSNotification){
    //Action take on Notification
}
```

or

```
@objc private func methodOFReceivedNotication(notification: NSNotification){
    //Action take on Notification
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, adding dynamic, but why? What's going on here?

Comment: @StevenMarlowe, this article([link](http://blog.untitledkingdom.co.uk/obj-c-vs-swift/)) might be helpful.

Comment: Great answer + article @YiminLin   
I just think that the dynamic keyword should be the first option (since its less of a "workaround")

Answer (score 10):

Have you considered using `-addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:`?

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("NotificationIdentifier", object: nil, queue: nil, usingBlock: {
    [unowned self] note in
    self.methodOFReceivedNotication(note)
})
```

or instead of calling the private method, just performing the action.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("NotificationIdentifier", object: nil, queue: nil, usingBlock: {
    [unowned self] note in
    // Action take on Notification
})
```

Comment: I like this solution because Swift puts a lot of weight into "being safe" and it's safer to be able to explicitly call a method rather than provide a quoted string for the method name (for the selector).  Then if you change the method signature later, you'll actually have a compile error rather than a runtime error.