# Selector string from Swift function

Tags: swift

Given a function reference, is there a way in Swift to get the name of that function as a string suitable for passing to `NSSelectorFromString`?

I'd like to wrap `NSNotificationCenter`'s `addObserver` with a version that takes a function reference instead of a selector string:

```
addObserver(self, function: someCallback, name: "some notification", object: nil)
```

But `addObserver` takes a String selector argument.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24049111/2477632

Comment: Yes, I know how to invoke `addObserver` in swift. But I want to create a new method that takes the function reference as an argument and converts it to a string.

Comment: "But addObserver takes a String selector argument." No. It takes a Selector argument. They are not the same thing (even if you can sometimes use a string in Swift where a Selector is expected).

Comment: Point taken @matt. But all of `Selector`'s initializers take String arguments. Is there a way to create a `Selector` representing an existing function other than using a string literal?

Answer (score 4):

You're reinventing an unnecessary wheel. NSNotificationCenter *already* has an observation method that takes a function (what Objective-C calls a "block"):

```
addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:
```

So just use that.

Comment: Thanks. I'd forgotten about this version. See my answer for how I've implemented my original approach.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I'm leaving this here for interest, but it's way too complicated (got wrapped up in how the question was asked, rather than the goal). Beyond the existing block-based approach, there's also [this handy extension to it](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQNotificationListenerKit).

---

I wouldn't do it this way. It's too limiting because it would exclude function literals (anonymous functions).

Instead, I would play this game:

- Create an dictionary property mapping `[String: Void -> ()]` (string to function)
- When you register a new function, make up a unique, random key and store the function you're passed in your dictionary with that key.
- Register with the selector `observer_dispatcher_<key>` (or whatever prefix you like).
- Implement `resolveInstanceMethod:` to dynamically create any `observer_dispatcher_` method you're requested. They can all point to the same `IMP`, something like:

(assuming this is good Swift; I haven't tried it):

```
 void _observer_dispatcher(self: AnyObject, _cmd: Selector) {
    let name = // strip the leading stuff off of _cmd
    if let f = self.dispatchTable[name] {
         f()
     }
 }
```

(This is still pretty sloppy; I'll have to think about the correct correct impl more, but this is the direction I'd go in.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd still like to find an answer to my original question, but based on @matt's suggestion, I'm currently using this extension:

```
extension NSNotificationCenter {

    class func addObserver(function: (NSNotification!) -> (), name: String? = nil, object: AnyObject? = nil, queue: NSOperationQueue? = nil) {
        defaultCenter().addObserverForName(name, object: object, queue: nil, usingBlock: function)
    }

}
```

Since it implicitly uses `defaultCenter()` and provides defaults for `object` and `queue`, which I'd almost always pass nil for, it allows for a more succinct call:

```
NSNotificationCenter.addObserver(doSomething, name: "some notification")
```

I like that it links against the actual function (`doSomething`), rather than a string representation. It's not a general purpose extension, but I think it covers 90% of the cases where I register for notifications.