# XCTest and using mock objects as notification receivers

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xctest, xctestexpectation

In XCTest with swift you can define mock objects in the test function you need it in. Like so

```
func testFunction(){
    class mockClass: AnyObject{
        func aFunction(){
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use these mock objects to test that another function sends out the correct notification given a certain condition (in my case that the success notification is broadcast with a 204 status code to an object.

The problem I am having is that i get an "Unrecognised selector" runtime error even though the `deletedSuccess()` function is clearly there/

Heres some code dump

```
func testDelete(){
    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("Post was deleted")

    class MockReciever : AnyObject {
        func deleteSuccess(){
            println("delete successfull")
            expectation.fulfill()
        }
    }

    let mockReciever = MockReciever()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(mockReciever, selector: "deleteSuccess", name: PostDeletedNotification, object: post)
    let response = NSHTTPURLResponse(URL: NSURL(), statusCode: 204, HTTPVersion: nil, headerFields: nil)
    let request = NSURLRequest()
    post.deleteCompletion(request, response: response, data: nil, error: nil)

    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(30, handler: { (error) -> Void in
        if error != nil{
            XCTFail("Did not recieve success notification")
        } else {
            XCTAssertTrue(true, "post deleted successfully")
        }
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(mockReciever)
    })
}
```

Is there some sort of problem with using mock objects and selectors like this that I don't know about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to implement mock objects to test notifications. There is a `-[XCTestCase expectationForNotification:object:handler:]` method.

And here's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049020/nsnotificationcenter-addobserver-in-swift) on how to receive notifications from NSNotificationCenter in Swift classes that do not inherit from NSObject. Technically it's a duplicate question.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate question. I tried making mock objects of NSObject, and UIViewController (since it's a view controller that receives the notification in the app itself) and I got the same error every time. My question is whether mock objects can be used as the observer.

I will try the expectationForNotification function tomorrow though and let you know if it works

Comment: Worked a treat thanks. Even using the completion block for testing things that should happen before the notification is sent

Comment: Yeah, it's a great way to test NSNotificationCenter. There is a similar method to test KVO too.