# How to load the link i’m navigating in my webView when clinking on the Smart App Banner?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am using a Smart App Banner to promote an application and it works well! However, I would like to load the link i’m navigating in my webView(I am using a WKWebView) when clinking on the Smart App Banner.

Here is the following code that I am using in my AppDelegate.swift file:

```
var vc = ViewController()

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL,sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

let url1 = NSURL(string:"\(url)")!

self.vc.webView!.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url1!))
return true
}
```

and it's not working!

Comment: you show the viewcontroller, adding it to navigationController or showing it as a modal?

Comment: I've got only one viewcontroller in the application that i've used to display my webView.

Comment: Usually your view controller is a class in a separate file. 
In app delegate you can post a notification and in the view controller observe it. For use NSNotificationCenter in swift:  [http://stackoverflow.com/a/24756761/4519092](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24756761/4519092)

Comment: It appears that the value of my webView returns nil, thats why i'm getting this error!

Comment: Yes because you create view controller by: ```var vc = ViewController()```. Are you using storyboard?

Comment: Yes I am using the storyboard. If I remove 'var vc = ViewController()' , how to call the webView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

in app delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL,sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

let url1 = NSURL(string:"\(url)")!

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("OpenLinkNotification", object: url1)

return true
}
```

in the view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "methodOfReceivedNotification:", name:"OpenLinkNotification", object: nil)
       ...
}

...

func methodOfReceivedNotification(notification: NSNotification){
    let url = notification.object as NSURL
    self.vc.webView!.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url!))
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```