# How to instantiate a ViewController from a didSelectItemAtIndexPath of a custom CollectionViewController which is a part of a tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift2, swift-protocols

I want to instantiate a `ViewController` from a custom `tableViewCell`(conforming to `UICollectionViewDelegate,` `UICollectionDatasource`) class which has a custom CollectionView embedded in it.The segue needs to be performed when a particular section of the CollectionView is selected. Already tried using protocols doesnt work!

```
my custom TableView class :-
   import UIKit


protocol transferDelegate{

func transfer(_: Int)

}


class ParentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{



@IBOutlet weak var parentCellHeader: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var feedPostUsername: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var feedPostUserDetails: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var feedPostDescription: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var feedPicturesCollectionView: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet weak var feedUserProfilePictures: CustomProfilepicture!



var transferingDelegate : transferDelegate?

override func awakeFromNib() {


    super.awakeFromNib()

    feedPicturesCollectionView.dataSource = self
    feedPicturesCollectionView.delegate = self
    feedPicturesCollectionView.pagingEnabled = true
    feedPicturesCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

}




override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

}




required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

}




func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    return 1

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 10

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = feedPicturesCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("FeedPicturesCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedPhotosCell



    switch(indexPath.row){

    case 0 :   cell.feedImages.image = UIImage(named: "defaultProfilePic")

    case 1 :   cell.feedImages.image = UIImage(named: "image1")

    case 2 :   cell.feedImages.image = UIImage(named: "image2")

    case 3 :   cell.feedImages.image = UIImage(named: "image3")


    default : cell.feedImages.image = UIImage(named: "defaultProfilePic")

        }

        return cell


}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print(indexPath.row)

    transferingDelegate?.transfer(indexPath.row)


}


}
```

my viewController class : -

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,transferDelegate{

var xibName : String = "HomepageFeedCellHeader"


var lords : [String] = ["name1","name2","name3"]

var que : [String] = ["--","red","blue"]

var desc : [String] = ["abcE","defn","ghi"]

var  menProfilePictures : [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "image1")!,UIImage(named: "image2")!,UIImage(named: "image3")!]

@IBOutlet weak var parentTableView: UITableView!


var a : ParentTableViewCell = ParentTableViewCell()






override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()



    parentTableView.delegate = self
    parentTableView.dataSource = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return lords.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = parentTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ParentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ParentTableViewCell
    a.transferingDelegate = self
    cell.feedPostUsername.text = lords[indexPath.row]
    cell.feedPostUserDetails.text = queens[indexPath.row]
    cell.feedPostDescription.text = desc[indexPath.row]
    cell.feedUserProfilePictures.image = menProfilePictures[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func transfer(itemNo : Int) {

    print("call recieved in viewController from item \(itemNo)")

}



}
```

Comment: With the use of `NSNotificationCenter`.

Comment: What is `a.transferingDelegate = self`?, it must be `cell.transferingDelegate = self`.

Comment: @BhumitMehta i am  new to this , can you please elaborate!

Comment: @Nirav  YEAH THAT SOLVED IT.....a was `var a : ParentTableViewCell = ParentTableViewCell()`  but why was i wrong? can you explain please!..

Comment: While your problem is fixed I would recommand you to go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049020/nsnotificationcenter-addobserver-in-swift this thread which explains how to use notification center to pass messages. Also go through this tutorial https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/08/fundamentals-of-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift/. It will help you in future, NSNotification approach is much cleaner than delegate.

Comment: @BhumitMehta thanks a lot!... do you guys have a discord forum or a group or something , where you could possibly add me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AchintyaGupta you need to set the delegate to the cell of your `UITableView` so that it will call your delegate method, and that cell must be from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Thnaks...now i am trying to pass an image between these two ViewControllers via      `imagePopOverScene?.detailImage.image = menProfilePictures[itemNo]`      but it gives me an error of `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` this is my array      `var  menProfilePictures : [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "image1")!,UIImage(named: "image2")!,UIImage(named: "image3")!]`

Comment: @AchintyaGupta Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` problem is solved. This is the answer of your second issue that you are mention in comment. You can not assign the image the `imageView`, if it is not in the `navigation` hierarchy. Your problem is that you `detailImage` is nil because this `ViewController` is not loaded in the window hierarchy. To solve your problem just do like this

```
imagePopOverScene?.selImage =  menProfilePictures[itemNo]
```

Now declare `selImage` in your `imagePopOverScene` like this

```
var selImage: UIImage!
```

Also  add follwing line in your `viewDidLoad` of `imagePopOverSceneVC`

```
self.detailImage.image = self.selImage
```

This will solve your problem