# How To Call a func within a Closure

Tags: swift, block, cllocation, completionhandler

In a model's class `Location`, I get the name of the current city:

```
var currentLatitude: Double!
var currentLongitude: Double!
var currentLocation: String!
var currentCity: String!

func getLocationName() {

    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: currentLatitude, longitude: currentLongitude)

    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { placemarks, error in
        guard let addressDict = placemarks?[0].addressDictionary else {
            return
        }
        if let city = addressDict["City"] as? String {
            self.currentCity = city
            print(city)
        }
        if let zip = addressDict["ZIP"] as? String {
            print(zip)
        }
        if let country = addressDict["Country"] as? String {
            print(country)
        }

        self.nowUpdateUI()
    })
}
```

In view controller I want to update the UI and update my label to show the current city. 
However, `self.currentCity = city` happens inside of a closure. So if I just run a func in view controller:

```
func updateUI() {
        cityLbl.text = Location.sharedInstance.currentCity
}
```

- I'm not getting anywhere because the closure haven't finished running. 
  I've been advised to add a completion handler to `getLocationName()` and inside of it, perform the call to a func that will update the UI. 
  However, from all the tutorials out there on closures, completion handlers, it is not clear to me how to achieve that. 
  How to construct a completion handler, pass it as an arg to `getLocationName()` and how to call `getLocationName` from view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle this situation you have multiple option.

1. **Create `delegate/protocol` with your Location class**

   - Create one protocol and implement that protocol method with your `ViewController` and declare its instance in your `Location` class. After then in the `completionHandler` of `reverseGeocodeLocation` call this delegate method. Check Apple documentation on [`Protocol`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) for more details.
2. **You can create `completionHandler` with your `getLocationName` method of `Location` class.**

   - Add `completionHandler` with `getLocationName` and called that `completionHandler` inside the `completionHandler` of `reverseGeocodeLocation` like this way.

     ```
     func getLocationName(completionHandler: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {

         let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
         let location = CLLocation(latitude: currentLatitude, longitude: currentLongitude)

         geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { placemarks, error in
             guard let addressDict = placemarks?[0].addressDictionary else {
                 completionHandler(false)
                 return
             }
             if let city = addressDict["City"] as? String {
                 self.currentCity = city
                 print(city)
             }
             if let zip = addressDict["ZIP"] as? String {
                 print(zip)
             }
             if let country = addressDict["Country"] as? String {
                 print(country)
             }
             completionHandler(true)
             //self.nowUpdateUI()
         })
     }
     ```

     Now in `ViewController` where you are calling this function call your `updateUI` method inside the completion block.

     ```
     Location.sharedInstance.getLocationName { (success) in
         if success {//If successfully got response
             self.updateUI()
         }
     }
     ```
3. **You can add observer for `(NS)NotificationCenter`.**

   - Register the observer with `(NS)NotificationCenter` and then post the notification inside the `completionHandler` of `reverseGeocodeLocation`. You can get more detail on this with this [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049020/nsnotificationcenter-addobserver-in-swift).

Comment: if you have any doubt feel free to ask question.

Comment: yep, i'm not fluent in programming yet, can you show the implementation of the 2nd option that you offer? 
(given that updateUI( ) is a method in view controller, not in Location, where getLocationName is implemented. )

Comment: @Mr_Vlasov So you want to use `completionHandler` with method. Are you working with Swift 3?

Comment: i'm struggling with finding a good tutorial or simple explanation on completion handlers. Apples documentation has all that unnecessary intermediate staff right in the article where they introduce closures. 
Could you suggest any good sources for closures theory? 
Trying to grasp the logic of its usage, not the syntax.

Comment: @Mr_Vlasov Check this http://alanduncan.me/2014/06/08/Swift-completion-blocks/ and http://michaelkral.com/learn-swift-closures/ also this one https://www.codebeaulieu.com/35/how-to-use-completion-handlers-in-swift-2

Answer (score 0):

This entire piece of your code:

```
completionHandler: { placemarks, error in
        guard let addressDict = placemarks?[0].addressDictionary else {
            return
        }
        if let city = addressDict["City"] as? String {
            self.currentCity = city
            print(city)
        }
        if let zip = addressDict["ZIP"] as? String {
            print(zip)
        }
        if let country = addressDict["Country"] as? String {
            print(country)
        }

        self.nowUpdateUI()
    }

)
```

is *already* happening in the completionHandler (which happens after everything is finished) Just also run your `updateUI()` inside the completionHandler. So your end code would be :

```
completionHandler: { placemarks, error in
        guard let addressDict = placemarks?[0].addressDictionary else {
            return
        }
        if let city = addressDict["City"] as? String {
            self.currentCity = city
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                updateUI() 
        }
        }
        if let zip = addressDict["ZIP"] as? String {
            print(zip)
        }
        if let country = addressDict["Country"] as? String {
            print(country)
        }

        self.nowUpdateUI()
    }

)
```

The reason you have to use `DispatchQueue.main` is because your completionHandler is on a backgroundqueue but you MUST always do you UI related stuff from your mainQueue—so users get the fastest changing in their UI without any glitches. Imagine if you were doing on a background thread and it was happening slow

Comment: but updateUI() is a func from view controller where the location label is declared. 
Should I create an instance of view controller and call the func?

Comment: @Mr_Vlasov I see, No you shouldn't do that. You should do what **Nirav D** has suggested

Answer (score 0):

```
// I thing issue back ground thread you need to update your UI in main thread
var currentLatitude: Double!
var currentLongitude: Double!
var currentLocation: String!
var currentCity: String!

func getLocationName() {

    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: currentLatitude, longitude: currentLongitude)

    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { placemarks, error in
        guard let addressDict = placemarks?[0].addressDictionary else {
            return
        }
        if let city = addressDict["City"] as? String {
            self.currentCity = city
            print(city)
        }
        if let zip = addressDict["ZIP"] as? String {
            print(zip)
        }
        if let country = addressDict["Country"] as? String {
            print(country)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.nowUpdateUI()
            // Update your UI in main thread
        }

    })
}
```