# How to pass data from ViewModel Layer to View Layer

Tags: ios, swift

I don't know how to pass data from my viewModel to my view and finally show the data in the view, my view model class is:

```js
class MainViewModel {

    let sessionController: SessionController
    weak var mainViewCoordinator: MainViewCoordinator?
    public var fakeUsers: [User]?

    init(sessionController: SessionController = SessionController()) {
        self.sessionController = sessionController
    }

    func viewDidLoad() {
        Service.instance.execute(resource: User.fake) { (result) in
            print("\n result \(result)\n")
            self.fakeUsers = result.value
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Unbox Swift JSON decoder, and the printed result is is and array of User objects something like this:

```js
([
  User(id: "5851ac2615801e2348e4ea07", 
       birthDate: "2016-09-17T07:22:09.985Z", 
       msisdn: "912 065 979", 
       email: "rosa_bravo@yahoo.com", 
       profileImageUrl: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/...", 
       repPoints: 41607, 
       created: "2016-12-14T20:31:34.185Z", 
       displayName: "Victoria Escobedo"), 
  User(id: "5851ac2615801e2348e4ea09", 
       birthDate: "2016-05-06T11:38:23.678Z", 
       msisdn: "958842030", 
       email: "francisca_barrios@gmail.com", 
       profileImageUrl: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/...", 
       repPoints: 71408, 
       created: "2016-12-14T20:31:34.198Z", 
       displayName: "Gonzalo Rascón"), 
   User(id: "5851ac2615801e2348e4ea08", 
        birthDate: "2016-05-29T18:12:32.423Z", 
        msisdn: "905534639", 
        email: "ral0@gmail.com", 
        profileImageUrl: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/...", 
        repPoints: 24164, 
        created: "2016-12-14T20:31:34.195Z", 
        displayName: "Ramiro Dueñas"),
   ...
])
```

And I would like to pass the result to the View Layer (MainViewController) to show each User in table view cells:

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet var tableview:UITableView!
var viewModel: MainViewModel = MainViewModel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    viewModel.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableview?.reloadData()
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Action", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(action))
}

func action() {
    viewModel.userDidSelectItem(identifier: "xxxx")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return viewModel.fakeUsers?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "fakeUserObjectCell") as! MainTableViewCell
    cell.fakeUserObject = viewModel.fakeUsers?[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detailSegue" {
        let detailMainViewController = segue.destination as! DetailMainViewController
        if let indexPath = tableview.indexPath(for: sender as! MainTableViewCell) {
            detailMainViewController.id = viewModel.fakeUsers?[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].id
        }
    }
}
```

}

I know I have to implement `self.tableview?.reloadData()` to show the fakeusers but I don't know how to pass the data and finally show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `Service.instance.execute()` in `viewModel.viewDidLoad()` is a async call. It have not completed the fetching and you have call `self.tableview?.reloadData()` Therefore this likely resulted in `0` rows.

I would suggest to change `ViewModel` `viewDidLoad()` to a completion call

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    Service.instance.execute(resource: User.fake) { (result) in
        print("\n result \(result)\n")
        self.fakeUsers = result.value
    }
}
```

Like this:

```
func loadUsers(completion: () -> ()) {
    Service.instance.execute(resource: User.fake) { (result) in
        print("\n result \(result)\n")
        self.fakeUsers = result.value
        completion()
    }
}
```

Therefore in the `MainViewController`, `viewDidLoad`, you can change the call to only `reloadData()` when is ready.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    viewModel.loadUsers {
        self.tableview?.reloadData()
    }
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Action", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(action))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Declare a public var `public var fakeUsers: [User]?` in `MainViewModel`
- Update `fakeUsers` in `MainViewModel`'s `viewDidLoad()`
- No need of a `fakeUsers` var in `MainViewController`
- `numberOfRowsInSection` in `MainViewController` now returns the count of `fakeUsers` set by `MainViewModel` like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {   
    return viewModel.fakeUsers?.count ?? 0
}
```

Similarly, for `cellForRowAt indexPath:`

**EDIT:**

The `Service.instance.execute` API call won't return immediately, but when it does, the data array should be updated with new content & the table requested to be refreshed. 
But now the problem is that we cannot have `table` access in `MainViewModel`. 
So, when the `Service` fetch completes, we can [notify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049020/nsnotificationcenter-addobserver-in-swift) `MainViewController` to perform a `table.reloadData()`
*I hope you can come up with the code for this bit*, you'll need to start here:

```
class MainViewModel {
    ...

    func viewDidLoad() {
        Service.instance.execute(resource: User.fake) { (result) in
            print("\n result \(result)\n")
            self.fakeUsers = result.value
            // Edu, the table refresh notification is to be fired from here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just edited the code, but I'm forgetting something because the issue persist

Comment: @Edu Yeah, we missed a component in the first flow, check edit.