# NotificationCenter is not calling the selector

Tags: ios, swift3, observers, notificationcenter

I've searched about this but the problem still exist for me. I found [this great question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049020/nsnotificationcenter-addobserver-in-swift) but unfortunately it didn't work for me. This is the first time I'm working with `NotificationCenter` and the need to use this first occurs when I wanted to pass data to a viewcontroller under a tab of [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip).

So here is how I am posting the Notification:

```
if let doc_ID = mainDoctorsArray[sender.tag].doctors_id {

            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("docID"), object: nil, userInfo: ["value" : doc_ID])
        }
```

In the class I've made for observing this notification I'm calling `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(gotDocID), name: Notification.Name("docID"), object: nil)`

The selector method is:

```
func gotDocID(notification:NSNotification) {

let userInfo:Dictionary<String,String> = notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<String,String>

if let item = userInfo["value"] {
    getDoctorDetails(docID: Int(item)!)
    //print(item,self)
  }
}
```

I've also tried adding observer as:
`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AvailableViewController.gotDocID(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("docID"), object: nil)` but still same result.

The issue is that `func gotDocID(notification:NSNotification)` is not being called.

**UPDATE**

Class which is posting the notification is `ViewController.swift` and the class which has the observer is `AvailableViewController.swift`

Based on a comment I've changed observer to `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AvailableViewController.gotDocID(notific‌​ation:)), name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)` and this error is generated.
[image]
and also by doing the follow I'm getting the same error.
[image]

> Value of type 'AvailableViewController' has no member 'gotDocID'

Comment: what is the nullcheck result of mainDoctorsArray[sender.tag].doctors_id?

Comment: where are you observing it same class or some other class?

Comment: @karthikeyan in some other class

Comment: @MingZhu The result of doc_ID is: 24 which is correct

Comment: Check your selector
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourClassName.methodOfReceivedNotification(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)

Comment: @karthikeyan see my updated question this comment which you just posted didn't work.

Comment: @ChaudhryTalha check my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155393/discussion-between-karthikeyan-and-chaudhry-talha).

Answer (score 2):

Add `@objc` to your function

```
@objc func gotDocID(notification:NSNotification) {

}

// Define identifier

let notificationName = Notification.Name("docID")

// Register to receive notification

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AvailableViewController.gotDocID(notification:)), name: notificationName, object: nil)

// Post notification
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil)

// Stop listening notification
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: notificationName, object: nil);
```

Comment: I don't know why but I'm getting this error: Type `AvailableViewController' has no member 'gotDocID(notific‌​ation:)`

Comment: I have tested the code it not giving any error set cursor after `#selector(AvailableViewController.` and check for func in autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to post and get data.

```
//Post notification
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("docID", object: nil, userInfo: ["value" : doc_ID])

//Get data from observer
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AvailableViewController.gotDocID(_:)), name: "docID", object: nil)

//Method called after notification is posted.
func gotDocID(notification: NSNotification) {
  if let image = notification.userInfo?["value"] as? String {
  // do something with your data   
  }
 }
```

Comment: I'm getting `Type 'AvailableViewController' has no member 'gotDocID'` and I'm using swift 3.2 so `NSNotificationCenter` is `NotificationCenter` which I've converted as per your code but still this error. You can also see this error in the screenshot in update section of this question.

Comment: @ChaudhryTalha Use self.gotDocID(_:) instead of AvailableViewController.gotDocID(notific‌​ation:) and it will work. I have check this is working

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try **closure**

Make sure your post notification occures.

Change

```
 NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("docID") , object: ["value" : doc_ID])


NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name("docID"), object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notify) in
                        print(notify.object as!  Dictionary<String,String>)

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController  {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.gotDocID(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("docID"), object: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("docID"), object: nil, userInfo: ["value" : "123"])
    }

    @objc func gotDocID(notification:NSNotification) {
        let userInfo:[String: String] = notification.userInfo as! [String: String]
        if let item = userInfo["value"] {
            print(item,self)
        }
    }
}
```