# Change UIScrollView Offset to top from another viewController in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, nsnotificationcenter, swift4

I have `mainViewController` and inside have `scrollView` and I have `secondViewController`  I want to change `scrollView` offset to top from `secondViewController` when I want to try it with `NSNotificationCenter` gives me ;

> : unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff83e024200'

How can I fix it ?
My codes under below.

**mainViewController**

```
       override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: "gotop:", name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "gotop"), object: nil)

    }

  func gotop(){
         scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0, y:0), animated: false)
    }
```

**secondViewController**

```
@IBAction func goButton (sender : UIButton){

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "gotop"), object: nil)


    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049020/nsnotificationcenter-addobserver-in-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your addObserver code, selector should have below signature

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MainViewController.goTop(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("gotop"), object: nil)
```

Method handler for received Notification:

```
func goTop(notification: Notification){
   scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0, y:0), animated: false)
}
```

For posting notification

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("gotop"), object: nil)
```

Remove Notification in denit

```
deinit {
  NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver((self, name: Notification.Name("gotop"), object: nil)
}
```

Comment: Great it worked. Don't forget to remote notification in deinit method

Comment: what is in deinit ? I need to add extra coding ?

Comment: where can i put denit code ? after posting notification ?

Comment: same file where you have added observer, in MainViewController

Answer (score 2):

I have used below code in my project to add notification :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourViewController.gotop), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "gotop"), object: nil)
```

Try if it works in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

the definition of your "goTop" func is wrong :

instead of

```
func gotop(){
  //do your stuff
}
```

try this :

```
func gotop(notification : NSNotification){
   //do your stuff
}
```

let me know if this solve your problem.

Comment: trying I will let