# Swift NotificationCenter passing userInfo to observing view controller

Tags: ios, swift, notificationcenter

I'm trying to pass userInfo from an object to an observing view controller. For some reason it keeps crashing. Here's the code:

Observer:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(self.alarmFired(_:)),
        name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "AlarmFiringNotification"),
        object: nil)
```

Receiving function:

```
@objc func alarmFired(_ notification: UNNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    let title = userInfo["title"] as? String
    let body = userInfo["body"] as? String
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: body, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okAction)
}
```

Notification broadcasting:

```
public static func broadcastAlarmFiringNotification(with userInfo: [String: Any]) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "AlarmFiringNotification"), object: self, userInfo: userInfo))
}
```

Broadcasting call:

```
NotificationBroadcaster.broadcastAlarmFiringNotification(with: ["title": title, "body": body])
```

But it keeps crashing with this output:

```
2018-03-14 18:51:06.743621-0400 App[33718:871608] -[NSConcreteNotification request]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60c00005c860

2018-03-14 18:51:06.754868-0400 App[33718:871608] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteNotification request]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60c00005c860'
```

It crashes on the notification broadcasting (NotificationCenter.default.post...)

I'm really confused, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSNotificationCenter addObserver in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049020/nsnotificationcenter-addobserver-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UNNotification` class is not what you want here. Change the signature to:

```
@objc func alarmFired(notification: Notification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo
```