# Swift: Show UIAlert while waiting for semaphore

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, semaphore, cocoaasyncsocket

I'm using CocoaAsyncSocket pod to transfer data from measurement instrument to an iOS device. The transfer works pretty well, but I get in trouble, if I have to switch between different mobile instruments.

If I need to change the instrument / connect to another instrument, I have to wait for some events:

1. I have to be sure to be disconnected. This is typically done by waiting for `public func socketDidDisconnect(...)` included in the `GCDAsyncSocketDelegate`
2. I have to connect to the other instrument. If it is still the tcp interface, I have to wait for `public func socketDidConnectToHost(...)`

So there are two operations which take some time. Because there is no valid connection, the user just can wait. To inform the user what's going on, I would like to present an UIAlert until the mentioned events are finished. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need to wait for the semaphore in the first place? Typically `NotificationCenter` should be enough to raise an event (upon detecting the disconnection) to which your VC can subscribe to and update it's UI accordingly

Comment: I thought this would be the best method to synchronize the view. Well, if I try it like you said, how can I handle more than one event to wait for?

Comment: what is the other type of event apart from disconnect you'd like to synchronise with? Perhaps you could precisely describe timeline(s) of things happening to further illustrate your case.

Comment: @Kamil.S I hope the edit can help to understand me :)

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still not clear to me what exactly is happening. You want to react to the `socketDidDisconnect` by updating the VC's UI, fair enough. However the part " In my ViewController I would like to wait for the delegate func to be called and synchronize my connection status with my View. " confuses me. Is there anything else other than disconnect you're syncing with? That's why I insisted on precise timeline, make a drawing whatever, but be as explicit as possible on the sequence of events please.

Comment: Don’t wait and don’t use semaphores. The end.

Comment: @Kamil.S Okay, I think I mixed up more than one question. I tried to be as precise as I can to ask my main question. Hope it is clean now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Semaphores** seem way too low level for your case, unless you are doing it for educational purposes.

Using **NotificationCenter** instead:

1) Post a *"didDisconnectNotification"* (string name being arbitrary) from `socketDidDisconnect(...)` and in it's **corresponding** handler update your viewController UI indicating the user a connectivity problem.
2) Post a *"didConnectNotification"* from `socketDidConnectToHost(...)` and in it's handler (distinct from 1) dismiss the connectivity problem indicator^.

*Note:* On your viewController first appearance you would probably start with 2) so there's nothing yet to dismiss.

You can find numerous examples related to `NotificationCenter` on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24756761/5329717

In a scenario where the two aforementioned operations are independent (i.e. they can occur in any order relative to each other) the GCD mechanism to use would be **DispatchGroup**. It's somewhat closer to your attempt at using a semaphore, however you **don't need it either** because your 2 events (disconnect & connect) are **dependent** (i.e. their respective order of occurence is **fixed**).
An example valid usage case of **DispatchGroup** would be synchronising responses of many image fetch requests when you don't care about their order of arriving (you either get all of them or do not proceed).