# Xcode Swift How to know if the "shake to undo" in accessibility setting is enable

Tags: swift, xcode

In the settings of accessibility of the iphone we can activate or not the option of "shake to cancel". I would like to know if it is possible in swift to know if the setting is activated or not. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/1615103-isshaketoundoenabled):

```swift
UIAccessibility.isShakeToUndoEnabled
```

There's also a `NSNotification` sent when this setting is changed called [shakeToUndoDidChangeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/1615095-shaketoundodidchangenotification/).

Comment: Thanks. Can you show me an example for shakeToUndoDidChangeNotification please ? I don't understand.

Comment: You need to use `NotificationCenter` to receive updates. [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049020/nsnotificationcenter-addobserver-in-swift) should prove useful.