# How to make a UIPageControl in ViewController update when PageViewController is swiped

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have three classes `OnboardingViewController`, `OnboardingPageViewController`, and `OnboardingContentViewController`.
In my ViewController class, I have a `UIPageControl` that updates whenever I press the `UIButton` "Next" beneath it. This is working as intended. However I want to make the `UIPageControl` updated according to when I swipe left/right on the `UIPageViewController`, but I'm not sure how to do this.

```swift
class OnboardingViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    
    var onboardingPageViewController: OnboardingPageViewController?
    
    @IBAction func nextButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let index = onboardingPageViewController?.currentPageIndex {
            switch index {
            case 0:
                onboardingPageViewController?.nextPage()
            case 1:
                onboardingPageViewController?.nextPage()
                nextButton.setTitle("Get Started", for: .normal)
            case 2:
                //present login ViewController after final next button is tapped
            default:
                break
            }
            pageControl.currentPage = index + 1
        }
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destination = segue.destination
        if let pageViewController = destination as? OnboardingPageViewController {
            onboardingPageViewController = pageViewController
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
class OnboardingContentViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel! 
    @IBOutlet var introLabel: UILabel!

    var index = 0
    var contentTitle = ""
    var intro = ""
    var imageFile = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        titleLabel.text = contentTitle
        introLabel.text = intro
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageFile)
    }
}
```

```swift
class OnboardingPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
    
    var pageTitle = ["Title1", "Title2", "Title3"]
    var pageIntro = ["Description1","Description2","Description3"]
    var pageImages = ["image1","image2","image3"]
    var currentPageIndex = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        dataSource = self
        delegate = self
        
        if let startingViewController = contentViewController(at: currentPageIndex) {
            setViewControllers([startingViewController], direction: .forward,animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func nextPage() {
        currentPageIndex += 1
        if let nextViewController = contentViewController(at: currentPageIndex){
            setViewControllers([nextViewController], direction:.forward, animated: true, completion:nil)
        }
    }
   
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var index = (viewController as! OnboardingContentViewController).index
        index -= 1
        return contentViewController(at:index)
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var index = (viewController as! OnboardingContentViewController).index
        index += 1
        return contentViewController(at:index)
    }
    
    func contentViewController(at index: Int) -> OnboardingContentViewController? {
        if index < 0 || index >= pageIntro.count {
            return nil
        }
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Onboarding", bundle: nil)
        if let pageContentViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"OnboardingContentViewController") as? OnboardingContentViewController {
                pageContentViewController.imageFile = pageImages[index]
                pageContentViewController.contentTitle = pageTitle[index]
                pageContentViewController.intro = pageIntro[index]
                pageContentViewController.index = index
                return pageContentViewController
        }
            return nil
    }

}
```

I tried adding the UIPageViewController delegate method to the first view controller but I'm finding that nothing is printing in the console. What am I missing?

```swift
class OnboardingViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let pageController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OnboardingPageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
        pageController.delegate = self
        
    }

 func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        if completed == true {
            print("change page control number")
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you do `let pageController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController...`, you're initializing a new copy of the page view controller. This is unrelated to the one that your users see.

```
/// no!
let pageController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OnboardingPageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
pageController.delegate = self
```

Instead, you need to reference the existing page view controller that was added in the storyboard. It's automatically added as the first child of `OnboardingViewController`, so you can get it using [`self.children[0]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621452-children).

```
class OnboardingViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    
    /// here!
    var pageController: UIPageViewController {
        return self.children[0] as! UIPageViewController
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pageController.delegate = self
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        if completed == true {
            print("change page control number")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to create a post notification [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049020/nsnotificationcenter-addobserver-in-swift)

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    var index = (viewController as! OnboardingContentViewController).index
    index -= 1
    // post notification here with sending index value
    return contentViewController(at:index)
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    var index = (viewController as! OnboardingContentViewController).index
    index += 1
    // post notification here with sending index value
    return contentViewController(at:index)
}
```

And listen in `viewDidLoad` of `OnboardingViewController`